npm install error: [NOT_IMPLEMENTED] /-/npm/v1/security/* not implemented yet
when I pull code for vscode.and install vs2022.cmd 'npm install' error. I try reinstall、clean node_module but not work.
is win10 not support the vscode 1.94.0? also nodejs version is high, or my memory is small(8G).
*** Invalid C/C++ Compiler Toolchain. Please check https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#prerequisites.
D:\vscode-master\build\npm\preinstall.js:30
                throw new Error();
Node.js v22.9.0

40 http fetch POST 404 https://registry.npmmirror.com/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 1049ms
41 silly audit bulk request failed [object Object]
42 http fetch POST 404 https://registry.npmmirror.com/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 36ms
43 verbose audit error HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - POST https://registry.npmmirror.com/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick - [NOT_IMPLEMENTED] /-/npm/v1/security/* not implemented yet
43 verbose audit error     at D:\npmInstall\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\lib\check-response.js:95:15
43 verbose audit error     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
43 verbose audit error     at async [getReport] (D:\npmInstall\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\audit-report.js:336:21)
43 verbose audit error     at async AuditReport.run (D:\npmInstall\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\audit-report.js:106:19)
43 verbose audit error     at async Arborist.reify (D:\npmInstall\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:268:24)
43 verbose audit error     at async Install.exec (D:\npmInstall\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:150:5)
43 verbose audit error     at async Npm.exec (D:\npmInstall\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:207:9)
43 verbose audit error     at async module.exports (D:\npmInstall\node_modules\npm\lib\cli\entry.js:74:5) {
43 verbose audit error   headers: [Object: null prototype] {
43 verbose audit error     server: [ 'Tengine' ],
43 verbose audit error     date: [ 'Mon, 23 Sep 2024 06:20:21 GMT' ],
43 verbose audit error     'content-type': [ 'application/json' ],
43 verbose audit error     'transfer-encoding': [ 'chunked' ],
43 verbose audit error     connection: [ 'keep-alive' ],
43 verbose audit error     'strict-transport-security': [ 'max-age=5184000' ],
43 verbose audit error     via: [ 'kunlun7.cn7036[,404666]' ],
43 verbose audit error     'timing-allow-origin': [ '*' ],
43 verbose audit error     eagleid: [ 'da620c9b17270724218973624e' ],
43 verbose audit error     'x-fetch-attempts': [ '1' ]
43 verbose audit error   },
43 verbose audit error   statusCode: 404,
43 verbose audit error   code: 'E404',
43 verbose audit error   method: 'POST',
43 verbose audit error   uri: 'https://registry.npmmirror.com/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick',
43 verbose audit error   body: {
43 verbose audit error     error: '[NOT_IMPLEMENTED] /-/npm/v1/security/* not implemented yet'
43 verbose audit error   },
43 verbose audit error   pkgid: undefined
43 verbose audit error }
44 silly audit error [object Object]
45 silly audit report null
46 verbose stack Error: command failed
53 verbose os Windows_NT 10.0.17763
54 verbose node v22.9.0
55 verbose npm  v10.8.3


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I installed vs2022 tools, but for some unknown reason, the system's environment variables are missing. Just configure vs2022_install and it's ok
